# Writing to a SQLite Database in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Using Visual Studio/ Windows Forms, I am trying to write data to a SQLite DB.
The Event handler for the "submit" button is supposed to take the information in the relevant textboxes and write them to the corresponding fields in the DB. 
The database connection and location is handled in the dbConnect class, and works as the login form works.
When the submit button is clicked however, nothing happens, no error message, nothing.
Can you see anything glaring?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //write new customer data to db
                using (SQLiteConnection dbcon = new SQLiteConnection(conString))
                {
                    dbcon.ConnectionString = dbConnect.source;
                    string sql;
                    {
                        sql = "INSERT INTO guest(forename,surname,telnumber,email,address)"
                            + " Values(@f,@l,@tel,@em,@ad)";
                    }
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbcon))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f", foreTB.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("l", surTB.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tel", telTB.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("em", emailTB.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ad", addTB.Text);

                        //perform db operation
                        dbcon.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dbcon.Close();
                    }
                }
                //display relevant action feedback message
                {
                    showlabel("New Customer Added OK", 4000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: your params appear with `@` in the SQL but lack it in the `AddWithValue` method.  BTW `AddWithValue` is very bad especially with SQLite which is typeless.  You should use the `Add(string param, dbType type).Value = xxx` form so you can specify the datatype rather than make  it guess

Comment: Are you certain the event handler is set up for your button?

Comment: @Plutonix I've tried adding the @s, no change. I will change the AddWithValue things shortly see if that works, thank you.

Comment: Add vs AddWithValue is more precautionary against trashing your db.  Set a break point and see if the method is getting called.  If not, it may not be hooked up

Comment: @Babak I have taken some code from other projects so i am not certain, however the projects are very similar doing the same thing

Comment: Events still have to be wired up - you cant just paste code and have it magically find and use methods as you want.  Use the event pane in the props window to see if the click handler is hooked up

Comment: @Plutonix Ah I see what was meant now, yes the click is handled, Thank you for the Add suggestion, am figuring it out and trying to plug it in now.

Comment: you can also change it to`var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` the return tells you how many rows were affected - view it in the debugger

Comment: @Plutonix I managed, in a roundabout way. To get it to work. Much appreciated!